# FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/49.0.0/native-modules failed

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, mobile-application

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0XM3.png)

FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/49.0.0/native-modules failed, reason:
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users...\Documents\MobileApplication...\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1501:11)

Trying to create a new react native mobile application using expo. Both 'npm start' and 'npx expo start' return this error. I have tried deleting node_modules, packages.json, expo ; reinstalling expo, expo cli, node, npm e.tc but nothing works. Please explain what is wrong and help with a solution.